# adding logger to exclude it from console

Tags: xml, log4j2

I migrated from Ireport 5.5 to Studio 6.4 libs and I started to see some news DEBUG and TRACE logs and I decided to exclude them

```
Información:   2017-09-15 08:14:09,920 TRACE beanutils.MethodUtils [] - Matching name=addElement on class net.sf.jasperreports.engine.design.JRDesignBand
Información:   2017-09-15 08:14:09,921 DEBUG digester.Digester [] -   Fire end() for FactoryCreateRule[className=net.sf.jasperreports.engine.xml.JRTextFieldFactory, attributeName=null, creationFactory=net.sf.jasperreports.engine.xml.JRTextFieldFactory@58abbf35]
Información:   2017-09-15 08:14:09,921 DEBUG digester.Digester [] - [FactoryCreateRule]{jasperReport/pageFooter/band/textField} Pop net.sf.jasperreports.engine.design.JRDesignTextField
Información:   2017-09-15 08:14:09,922 DEBUG Digester.sax [] - ignorableWhitespace(     )
Información:   2017-09-15 08:14:09,922 DEBUG Digester.sax [] - endElement(http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports,band,band)
```

so I added to my **log4j2.xml** the logger name="digester", but it's not working, I keep seeing the logs in the console

```
 <Loggers>
        <Logger name="org.hibernate" level ="warn"></Logger>
----->  <Logger name="digester" level="warn"></Logger> <-------!!!!!!
        <Logger name="net.sf.jasperreports" level="info"></Logger>
        <Logger name="org.apache.commons.beanutils.converters" level="warn"></Logger>
        <Logger name="com.mchange" level="info"></Logger>
        <Root level="all">
            <AppenderRef ref="console"/>
            <AppenderRef ref="logfile" level="error"/>
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I forgot that I have configured the "precision" for the appender  **%c{2}**:
org.apache.commons.digester

```
<Console name="console" target="System.out">
            <RegexFilter regex=".*(Javassist Enhancement failed|could not create proxy factory for).*" onMatch="DENY" onMismatch="ACCEPT"/>
            <PatternLayout pattern="%d %-2p %c{2} %x - %m%n"/> 
</Console>
```

And because of this I was not seeing the completed packages which I had to add to the Logger to works properly